# How would I get every text and voice channel and denying @ everyone to read it, and then allowing another role to read and send?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I wondered how when the bot is added to a guild, I can make it get every text and voice channel and then deny @ everyone access to read it, but then allow another role called 'Verified' to read it?
I am using the rewrite version of Discord.py

EDIT: I found how to change the permissions using

```
await message.channel.set_permissions(message.author, read_messages=True, send_messages=False)
```

But I still don't know how to apply this on every channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this here for others, even though you've gotten this answered on the Discord ;)

You'd need to iterate through each channel in a guild via `Guild.channels`

Answer (score 0):

This will only change things for the user who sent the message.  To block everyone, you must set permissions for `Guild.default_role` instead.  The below command accepts an existing role and any number of members.  It gives the invoker and all those members that role, and then disables reading messages for everyone without that role.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx, role: discord.Role, *members: discord.Member):
    for member in (ctx.author, *members):
        await member.add_roles(role, reason=f"Verify command by {ctx.author.id}")
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
        await channel.set_permissions(role, read_messages=True)

bot.run("Token")
```